# What can I do other than changing the file name when my file name is 'web_automation\pra.txt'?

Tags: python

```
with open('web_automation\new.txt', 'a', encoding='UTF-8') as file:
```

when i type this, the color of \n changes and says invalid argument: web_automation\new.txt.
I think it is because my file name starts with \n but is there any other way I can solve this other than changing the file name?

Answer (score 1):

escape the first \ with another 'web_automation\\new.txt'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).